# ¿Cómo manipular correctamente este archivo?

Tags: python, subida-de-archivos

Estaba probando algo y me encuentro con este problema.  Pongo un ejemplo simple para que se entienda o me digan.
El code:

```
def escribe(lines):
    f = open('Demo3.txt','a')
    entrada = str(lines)
    f.writelines(entrada)
    f.writelines('\n')

for i in range(0, 100, 5):
    escribe(i)
```

La salida:

```
0
2
4
6
8
XX
```

La 'x' representa una línea más. Obviamente, pertenece al for.

Para evitar esta línea extra. ¿Alguna recomendación? ¿Manejar el `range(x)`? ¿Otra implementación?

Estuve buscando algunas soluciones pero no la encuentro.

Gracias.

Comment: Usar el metodo write en la ultima iteración. Nota: Acuerdate de cerrar el archivo, puedes abrirlo antes del bucle. La función escribe recibirá dos paratmetro archivo y linea(def escribe(f,lines)), para así no estar llamando a la función open cada rato. Y después del bucle poder cerrar el archivo

Comment: @DanielBriceño. S'i, vi tu respuesta. Cuando ejecutas la primera vez, continua agregando al incio o al final una linea vacia.  Si quito el '\n' escribe el archivo como 23468. Creo que usare el strp para exterminar esa linea vacia.  GRacias, por tu respuesta. Take Care.

Comment: Salvo que quieras escribir "de uno en uno" los números en el fichero por algún motivo concreto, podrías almacenar los números en una lista **(como strings)** de nombre `nums`, por ejemplo, y una vez acabado el bucle, llamar a la función `escribe(nums)` para escribir todos los números "de una vez" `f.write('\n'.join(lines))`. Además soluciona el problema de la línea en blanco adicional al final del fichero.

Comment: @jabro para mejorar la propuesta, se puede usar comprensión de generador o un generador para evitar mantener todas las lineas en memoria.

Comment: @DanteS. `nums = (str(i) for i in range(0, 100, 5))` o `nums = map(str, range(0, 100, 5))` serían mejores opciones, como bien dices.

Comment: Me disculpo, me confundi sobre la funcion writelines, pense que agregaba una linea por defecto, pero se usa para escribir una lista de string en un archivo.

Answer (score 2):

```
def escribe( lineas ):
    f = open( "Demo3.txt", 'w' );
    f.writelines( lineas );
    f.close();

lineas = "0"
for i in range( 5, 100, 5 ):
    lineas += f"\n {i}"
    
escribe( lineas )
```

Acá te dejo una versión diferente, que no usa listas, ni genera el último salto de linea.
Simplemente instancio **`lineas`** con su primer valor (en este caso **`0`**), luego en el `for`, con cada iteración agrego a la cadena un salto de linea y el valor de **`i`**, cuando termina el `for`, llamo a **`escribe`** pasandole la cadena lista para guardar.

Answer (score 1):

Mi solucion es al momento de escribir la ultima linea no escribir el caracter de salto de linea.
Aconsejo abrir el archivo a fuera de la funcion, para no abrirlo cada rato y poder cerrarlo para liberar recursos.

```Python
def escribe(f,lines,endline):
    entrada = str(lines)
    f.writelines(entrada);
    if not lines==endline:
        f.writelines('\n')

f=open("Demo3.txt",'w');#Lo abrimos antes del bucle para no abrir el archivo cada ratico y tener la posibilidad de cerrarlo:
#Recuerda la opcion 'a' es append o escribir al final, yo elegi 'w' sobreescribir, asi se reinicia el archivo por cada vez que llames al programa.
last=100;
for i in range(0, last+5, 5):#+5 porque el bucle se ejecutara hasta 95. asi que le damos 5+ para los 100
    escribe(f,i,last);
    
f.close();#Cerramos el archivo y liberamos memoria.
```

Como dicen en los comentarios de arriba puedes usar una caracteristica de python(compresiones de lista) y aprovechar la funcion writelines(escribir una lista en un archivo en python:

```Python
#Pero como sabras writelines no da un salto de linea, asi que debes darsela tu.
lineas=(str(i)+'\n' for i in range(0,100,5));#Creamos una lista de lineas y lo guardamos en una tupla.
f.writelines(lineas);
f.write("100");#Escribimos la ultima linea:)
```

Completo:

```Python
f=open("Demo3.txt","w");
end=100;
f.writelines((str(i)+'\n' for i in range(0,end,5)));#Como no necesitamos la lineas despues se la lanzamos directamente a writelines.
f.write(str(end));#Agregamos la linea final:)
f.close();
```

Pero si aprovechamos la funcion writelines y la compresion de lista podemos hacer una funcion que escriba todo en el archivo y despues lo cierre:

```python
def escribe(lines=()):
    f=open("Demo3.txt",'w');
    f.writelines(lines);
    f.close();

lineas=[str(i)+'\n' for i in range(0,100,5)];
lineas.append("100");#La ultima linea sin \n
escribe(lineas);
```